# Append strings to array if found in paragraph using `.match` in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

I'm attempting to search a paragraph for each word in an array, and then output a new array with only the words that could be found.

But I've been unable to get the desired output format so far.

```
paragraph = "Japan is a stratovolcanic archipelago of 6,852 islands.
The four largest are Honshu, Hokkaido, Kyushu and Shikoku, which make up about ninety-seven percent of Japan's land area.
The country is divided into 47 prefectures in eight regions."

words_to_find = %w[ Japan archipelago fishing country ]

words_found = []

words_to_find.each do |w|
    paragraph.match(/#{w}/) ? words_found << w : nil
end

puts words_found
```

Currently the output I'm getting is a vertical list of printed words.

```
Japan
archipelago
country
```

But I would like something like, `['Japan', 'archipelago', 'country']`.

I don't have much experience matching text in a paragraph and am not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Could anyone give some guidance?

Comment: `words_found` is already what you want. It is `puts` that prints the array one element per line.

Comment: ah thanks. i need to readup on `puts` vs `p`

Comment: P.S. You can `p words_found` to see what it really is.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are using `puts` to print the elements of the array . appending `"\n"` to the end of every element "word":

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def run_me



    paragraph = "Japan is a stratovolcanic archipelago of 6,852 islands.
    the four largest are Honshu, Hokkaido, Kyushu and Shikoku, which make up about ninety-seven percent of Japan's land area.
    the country is divided into 47 prefectures in eight regions."

    words_to_find = %w[ Japan archipelago fishing country ]


    find_words_from_a_text_file paragraph , words_to_find



end



def  find_words_from_a_text_file( paragraph  , *words_to_find )
    words_found = []

    words_to_find.each do |w|
              paragraph.match(/#{w}/) ? words_found << w : nil
    end

    #  print array with enum .  
    words_found.each { |x| puts "with enum and puts : : #{x}" }

    # or just use "print , which does not add anew line"
    print "with print :"; print  words_found "\n"

    # or with p
    p words_found

end


run_me
```

outputs :

```
za:ruby_dir za$ ./fooscript.rb 
with enum and puts : : ["Japan", "archipelago", "fishing", "country"]
with print :[["Japan", "archipelago", "fishing", "country"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to do that. Both are case-indifferent.

**Use a regular expression**

```
r = /
    \b                               # Match a word break
    #{ Regexp.union(words_to_find) } # Match any word in words_to_find
    \b                               # Match a word break
    /xi                              # Free-spacing regex definition mode (x)
                                     # and case-indifferent (i)
  #=> /
  #   \b                             # Match a word break
  #   (?-mix:Japan|archipelago|fishing|country) # Match any word in words_to_find
  #   \b                             # Match a word break
  #   /ix                            # Free-spacing regex definition mode (x)
                                     # and case-indifferent (i)

paragraph.scan(r).uniq(&:itself)
  #=> ["Japan", "archipelago", "country"]
```

**Intersect two arrays**

```
words_to_find_hash = words_to_find.each_with_object({}) { |w,h| h[w.downcase] = w }
  #=> {"japan"=>"Japan", "archipelago"=>"archipelago", "fishing"=>"fishing",
       "country"=>"country"}  

words_to_find_hash.values_at(*paragraph.delete(".;:,?'").
                               downcase.
                               split.
                               uniq & words_to_find_hash.keys)
  #=> ["Japan", "archipelago", "country"]
```